# How to parse JSON dictionary inside object

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, uitableview, afnetworking

I am given the following JSON object. I am required to take the schedule and display the values inside of a table view converting them to the users local time zone. I am okay converting the time, however I am a little confused about how I should go about retrieving the schedule object and displaying the start and end dates inside a UITableView. I would greatly appreciate any help here. Thanks :).

```
{
    "zip": "70130 ",
    "phone": "",
    "ticket_link": "http://www.ticketmaster.com/New-Orleans-Convention-Center-tickets-New-Orleans/venue/221251",
    "state": "LA",
    "pcode": 4,
    "city": "New Orleans",
    "id": 15174,
    "tollfreephone": "",
    "schedule": [
      {
        "end_date": "2013-01-30 20:00:00 -0800",
        "start_date": "2013-01-30 13:00:00 -0800"
      },
      {
        "end_date": "2013-01-31 20:00:00 -0800",
        "start_date": "2013-01-31 08:00:00 -0800"
      },
      {
        "end_date": "2013-02-01 20:00:00 -0800",
        "start_date": "2013-02-01 08:00:00 -0800"
      },
      {
        "end_date": "2013-02-02 20:00:00 -0800",
        "start_date": "2013-02-02 08:00:00 -0800"
      },
      {
        "end_date": "2013-02-03 14:00:00 -0800",
        "start_date": "2013-02-03 08:00:00 -0800"
      }
    ],
    "address": "900 Convention Center Blvd",
    "image_url": "http://lorempixel.com/900/500/nightlife/?v=-632944306",
    "description": "",
    "name": "NFL Experience, Driven by GMC",
    "longitude": -90.06418,
    "latitude": 29.943351
  },
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's say that big lump of JSON you listed was downloaded and stored in an `NSData` variable called `jsonData`.

```
NSDictionary *json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:jsonData options:0 error:nil; // use an NSError if you want
NSArray *scheduleDates = json[@"schedule"];
for (NSDictionary *dates in scheduleDates) {
    NSString *endDateString = dates[@"end_date"];
    NSString *startDateString = dates[@"start_date"];
}
```

This is a way you can access the schedule and the dates within the schedule object. It is up to you to decide what to do with that info. Also, this is the quick dirty way of getting that info. There should be some nil-checking/type-safety/introspection done with mapping JSON to objects.